# How to make Firefox zoom more precision than 10% step?

Tags: firefox

Unfortunately the default Firefox 60.8.0esr zoom just allow 90%,80%,etc.(10% step) I want to set page zoom to 99%,98%,etc.(%1 or lower step)

Answer (score 5):

You can set the zoom steps in `about:config`, entry `toolkit.zoomManager.zoomValues`.
The default values are `.3,.5,.67,.8,.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.33,1.5,1.7,2,2.4,3`.

For more control, perhaps the add-on
[Zoom for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/zoom/)
would be helpful. The description includes:

> Set default zoom ratio and **zoom step**

This does not seem to work for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Wheel</kbd>.
In this
[Mozilla Support post](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=3038500),
there is this answer:

> Ctrl+wheel zooming is not referring "toolkit.zoomManager.zoomValues". It referres "zoom.minPercent" and "zoom.maxPercent" only. The value of 10% is *hard coded* (written in source code), so it is not customizable on Firefox itself.

The remedy in that post was to put the following code into
[userChrome.xml`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

  <bindings id="generalBindings"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
  xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
  xmlns:xbl="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl">

  <binding id="execute_javascript_code" extends="chrome://global/content/bindings/toolbarbutton.xml#menu">
    <implementation>
      <constructor>
        <![CDATA[

          (function() {
            if (window.ucjsExecuted)
              return;
            ucjsExecuted = true;
            gBrowser.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
              if (!event.ctrlKey)
                return;
              event.preventDefault();
              const lines = 3;
              let val = Number((ZoomManager.zoom - 0.05 * event.deltaY / lines).toFixed(2));
              if (val >= ZoomManager.MIN && val <= ZoomManager.MAX) {
                FullZoom.setZoom(val);
              };
            });
          })();

        ]]>
      </constructor>
    </implementation>
  </binding>
</bindings>
```

The amount of the scroll it given by the command:

```
          const lines = 3;
```

(I have not tested the above code.)

Comment: `toolkit.zoomManager.zoomValues` work except `Ctrl` + `Mouse wheel` zoom. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of 10% is hardcoded (ugh!), one workaround would be to use the:

- mouse wheel for coarse grained zoom adjustments (10%) step, and then
- keyboard for fine grained zoom adjustments (1%) step.

Below is the list of values to copy/paste into `toolkit.zoomManager.zoomValues` in `about:config` for convenience:

```
.01,.02,.03,.04,.05,.06,.07,.08,.09,.10,.11,.12,.13,.14,.15,.16,.17,.18,.19,.20,.21,.22,.23,.24,.25,.26,.27,.28,.29,.30,.31,.32,.33,.34,.35,.36,.37,.38,.39,.40,.41,.42,.43,.44,.45,.46,.47,.48,.49,.50,.51,.52,.53,.54,.55,.56,.57,.58,.59,.60,.61,.62,.63,.64,.65,.66,.67,.68,.69,.70,.71,.72,.73,.74,.75,.76,.77,.78,.79,.80,.81,.82,.83,.84,.85,.86,.87,.88,.89,.90,.91,.92,.93,.94,.95,.96,.97,.98,.99,1.00,1.01,1.02,1.03,1.04,1.05,1.06,1.07,1.08,1.09,1.10,1.11,1.12,1.13,1.14,1.15,1.16,1.17,1.18,1.19,1.20,1.21,1.22,1.23,1.24,1.25,1.26,1.27,1.28,1.29,1.30,1.31,1.32,1.33,1.34,1.35,1.36,1.37,1.38,1.39,1.40,1.41,1.42,1.43,1.44,1.45,1.46,1.47,1.48,1.49,1.50,1.51,1.52,1.53,1.54,1.55,1.56,1.57,1.58,1.59,1.60,1.61,1.62,1.63,1.64,1.65,1.66,1.67,1.68,1.69,1.70,1.71,1.72,1.73,1.74,1.75,1.76,1.77,1.78,1.79,1.80,1.81,1.82,1.83,1.84,1.85,1.86,1.87,1.88,1.89,1.90,1.91,1.92,1.93,1.94,1.95,1.96,1.97,1.98,1.99,2.00
```