# Firefox: Custom zoom under 1%?

Tags: firefox

Firefox allows customizing zoom levels via `toolkit.zoomManager.zoomValues` parameter in `about:config`.

However only those zoom levels work that are equal or higher than `zoom.minPercent`, which can be only an integer.

**How can I set up Firefox to zoom at less than 1%?**

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1464939/how-to-make-firefox-zoom-more-precision-than-10-step

Comment: How is that question relevant to mine?